# sendphotoasync() from hard drive

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

It would be more convenient for me to use the file from a computer, rather than download it from a specific link.

How i can send a picture from hard driver with using sendphotoasync in Telegram.Bot?

```
using System;
using Telegram.Bot;
using System.IO;

namespace iBot
{
    class Program
    {

        public static DateTime timeReplacement = DateTime.Parse(Config.TimeReplacement);
        private static TelegramBotClient client;

        public static void Main()
        {       

            client = new TelegramBotClient(Config.ApiToken);

           
            for(int i = 0; ; i++)
            {
                DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
                var date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();


                if (nowTime.ToShortTimeString() == timeReplacement.ToShortTimeString())
                {
                    client.SendPhotoAsync(Config.ChatId, Config.Link, $"Replacements: {date}"); 
                    client.StopReceiving();
                    break;
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `client.StopReceiving();`, Because bot doesn't get updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are using to send a picture is `SendPhotoAsync` and have this signature:
[source](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/blob/284542b95ba5aa87826d7d6c3f1a297a48e9c9e9/src/Telegram.Bot/ITelegramBotClient.cs)

```
    Task<Message> SendPhotoAsync(
            ChatId chatId,
            InputOnlineFile photo,
            string caption = default,
            ParseMode parseMode = default,
            IEnumerable<MessageEntity> captionEntities = default,
            bool disableNotification = default,
            int replyToMessageId = default,
            bool allowSendingWithoutReply = default,
            IReplyMarkup replyMarkup = default,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
            );
```

That means the picture is an instance of type `InputOnlineFile`.

I checked `InputOnlineFile` class

```
  public InputOnlineFile(Stream content)
            : this(content, default)
        {
        }
```

And it gets a `Stream` as parameter.

You easily create a stream from file with this snippet:

```
FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(pathSource,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

(Just don't forget to [dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.dispose?view=net-5.0) it after usage.)

So, the full snippet is like this:

```
FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(pathSource,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
InputOnlineFile file = new InputOnlineFile(fsSource);

... call here to SendPhotoAsync
```

Comment: Could you, please, provide the expected code prior to the SendPhotoAsync() method?

Comment: That's what I did ```FileStream fsSource = new FileStream("c:\\something",
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)```

Comment: type `InputOnlineFile` does not exists